# uninitialized constant (NameError) while including module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, module, rubygems

i am writing gem for my Rails app which calculates some stuff and uses class and modules.

Here is file structure.

```
root
->lib
-->finances
--->version.rb
--->finances.rb
--->calculator
----->formulas.rb
--->finalize
---->schedule.rb
-->finances.rb
```

Now `root/lib/finances.rb`

```
require "finances/version"
require "finances/finances"
require "finances/finalize/schedule"
require "finances/calculator/formulas"
```

`root/lib/finances/calculator/formulas.rb`

```
module Calculator
  module Formulas
    def method
    end
  end
end
```

`root/lib/finances/finalize/schedule.rb`

```
module Finalize
  class Schedule
    include ::Calculator::Formulas
  end
end
```

but I get `uninitialized constant Calculator (NameError)`

if i try to just use

```
::Calculator::Formulas.method
```

it throws `NoMethodError (undefined method`method' for Calculator::Formulas:Model):`

What exactly i am doing wrong. I cant seem to work around this. Could anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use `method` as `Formulas` 'module method', while you defined it as regular instance method. So it should be called on `RepaymentSchedule` instance:

```
rs = RepaymentSchedule.new
rs.method
```

Also, you need to make sure your loading order is correct. Here, you should `require` file containing `Formulas` module before you load `Schedule` class, otherwise you get uninitialized constant error.

Comment: yeah but how could i use Calculator::Formulas methods like normal model methods. I guess what i am asking how can i include thous methods inside Finalize::Schedule?

Comment: @user2945241 just like you're doing it, with `include`.

Comment: like include ::Calculator::Formulas? But it throws uninitialized constant Calculator (NameError) error

Comment: You should then require `formulas` before `schedule`. You get uninitialized constant because `Calculator::Formulas` module isn't yet defined when you try to include it.